# Make a new list from CSV

Tags: python, csv

So, I've search for a method to show a certain csv field based on input, and I've try to apply the code for my program. But the problem is I want to get a certain item in csv and make a new list from certain index.

I have csv file like this:

```
code,place,name1,name2,name3,name4
001,Home,Laura,Susan,Ernest,Toby
002,Office,Jack,Rachel,Victor,Wanda
003,Shop,Paulo,Roman,Brad,Natali
004,Other,Charles,Matthew,Justin,Bono
```

at first I have this code, and it works show all the row:

```
import csv

number = input('Enter number to find\n')

csv_file = csv.reader(open('residence.csv', 'r'), delimiter=",")

for row in csv_file:
    if number == row[0]:
        print (row)

**input : 001
**result : [001, Home, Laura, Susan, Ernest, Toby]
```

then, I try to make a certain row in the result to add the items to a new list. But it didn't work. Here's the code:

```
import csv

res = []
y = 2
number = input('Enter number to find\n')

csv_file = csv.reader(open('residence.csv', 'r'), delimiter=",")

for row in csv_file:

    if number == row[0]:
        while y <= 5:
            res.append(str(row[y]))
            y = y+1

print (res)

**input : 001
**expected result : [Laura, Susan, Ernest, Toby]
```

I want to make a new list that contains row `name1`, `name2`, `name3`, and `name4`, and then I want to print the list. But I guess the loop is wrongly placed or I missed something.

Comment: Could you update your question to include the input you enter, the output you actually receive, and the output you expect to receive?

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked! can you tell me which part i missed?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you could fix in your code.

1. You are not skipping the header line when iterating through the rows. This means you will not always match an actual row number.
2. Your `y` variable is not re-initialized. It would be more idiomatic to use a `for` loop instead of a `while` anyhow.
3. If more than one row match, it will break (see 2.). If you know you will never have more than one match, you should `break` after you append the values to the list.
4. Your file is never closed. Also it should be opened with `newline=''` (see [csv module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3))
5. Lastly, you match the actual string (`'001'`), vs. an integer (`1`), which could be the source of confusion when entering the input.

An updated version:

```
import csv

res = []
number = input('Enter number to find\n')

with open('residence.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
    next(csv_reader)  # Skip header line
    for row in csv_reader:
        if number == row[0]:
            for i in range(2, 6):
                res.append(str(row[i]))
            break

print(res)
```